# Values from the View are being read as null in MVC when Data Annotation and Bson Serializer are used together

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model which takes in the values from View and carries out Validation using Data Annotation.The Attributes have both Data Annotations and Bson Serializers together as shown below;

```
 public class SubscriberProfile 
    {
        //we need our data to come in the form of Bson format
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

        [BsonRequired]
        //[BsonRequired]
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "* Last Name Needs to Have a Minimum of 2 Characters"), BsonRequired]
        //[BsonRequired]
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }

        [BsonRequired]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [PricePlanValidation(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Price Plan Selection"),BsonRequired]
        //[BsonRequired]
        public string Price_Plan { get; set; }

        [ContactNumberValidation(ErrorMessage = "Contact Number Can only Contain (), + and numerical digits"),BsonRequired]
        //[BsonRequired]
        public string Contact_number { get; set; }
        [BsonRequired]
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [BsonRequired]
        public string Email_domain { get; set; }
        [BsonRequired]
        public string username { get; set; }
        [BsonRequired]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
        public DateTime dateofsubscription { get; set; }
```

The html code for the view is as follows:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Linq;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

@model SubscriberProfile
@{
    Layout = null;

}

 <div>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First_Name)" required>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_Name)
                </div><br />

                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Last_Name)" required>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_Name)
                </div><br />
                @if (Context.Session.GetString("LogonuserID") != null)
                {
                    <div>
                        <input type="email" class="input" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)" required readonly><br /><br />
                    </div><br />

                }
                else
                {
                    <div>
                        <input type="email" class="input" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)" required><br /><br />
                    </div><br />


                }


                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="contactnumber" placeholder="Contact Number" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Contact_number)" required>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact_number)
                </div><br />

                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="input" name="company" placeholder="Company" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Company)" required><br /><br />
                </div><br />

                <div>
                    <select name="priceplan" id="Price_Plan" required>
                        <option value="None"> Price Plan</option>
                        <option value="Free Trial">Free Trial</option>
                        <option value="6 Months Plan">6 Months Plan</option>
                        <option value="1 Year Plan">1 Year Plan</option>
                    </select>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price_Plan)
                </div>

                @{ 
                    string _buttonvalue = "\"Subscribe\"";
                    if (Context.Session.GetString("LogonuserID") != null)
                    {

                        _buttonvalue = "\"Save Details\"";

                    }
                }
                <div style="width:50%; margin:auto; margin-top:18px; margin-bottom:10px; align-content:center;">
                    <input type="submit" value=@Html.Raw(_buttonvalue) id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
```

The Model is not taking in my values that are entered into the view and are taking them as `null` values. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have change all values the way like this one
for example instead of

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Last_Name)" required>
```

use this:

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"value="@Model.Last_Name" required>
```

or maybe just this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Last_Name, new {@class="input"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The name attribute of my view for all input tags was not the same as the attribute name in my model.

This was causing the issue:

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First_Name)" required>
```

This was the fix

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="First_Name" placeholder="First Name" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First_Name)" required>
```